# Function returning only first element of an array

Tags: php, mysql

It should be simple, but I just can't figure it out. I have a function, which returns an array, fetched from a MySql database. The returned array should have 2 elements.

Here is the function:

```
function path_to_photo ($id)
{
   $query = mysql_query("Select path from photos1 where listingsdb_id = $id"); 
   $test_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

   return $test_array;
}

$one=2;
$test = path_to_photo($one); 
echo $test[0]; // --> this works fine
echo $test[1]; //-->this gives an error - undefined offset etc.
```

At first I thought my array returns actually only one element, but when I put

```
$query = mysql_query("Select path from photos1 where listingsdb_id=$id"); 
$test_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

return sizeof($test_array);
```

it gives me correct number of 2. I just don't understand what happens with the second index. Here is the output of the query in MySQL

```
mysql> select path from photos1 where listingsdb_id=2;
+------------------+
| path             |
+------------------+
| small_photo.jpg  |
| big_photo.jpg |
+------------------+
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` needs to be looped

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array containing the data for **the next row** in the result.

You said `Select path`, so there is only one column in the result, so the array length should be `1`.

If you want to get an array of all the `path`s then you will have to create an empty array, then call `mysql_fetch_array` **repeatedly**, putting each entry into the previously mentioned array in turn, and then return that array.